# Using webbrowser instead of Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make an auto yt searcher and this is as far as I got. I don't really understand on how to user selenium so I am using web-browser what's currently not happening is it is not opening or searching on the search bar (I used the XPath)or does anyone know a tutorial for selenium

```py
import webbrowser
import time


url = 'http://youtube.com'

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)

LastName = "nice"

time.sleep(2)

last = webbrowser.open('//*[@id="search"]')

webbrowser.get(LastName)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the actual Google Chrome Browser.

Instead you have to use **ChromeDriver** that works the same as the standard Chrome but you can use it with selenium.

You can download it [here.](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)

Once installed specify the correct path of chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

Python `webbrowser` module is not intended for interaction with UI objects. The purpose is just to open browser in order to display arbitrary web document from your python code.

If you check this [module page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) you will know that `webbrowser.open(...)` takes the URL as a parameter. It cannot work with xpath or other types of selectors. It cannot send other types of commands to browser except of "open that page".

So you have to deal with webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recomend to use selenium, because it is not very hard to learn and to integrate.

```
from selenium import webdriver

api = webdriver.Firefox()
api.get("https://www.youtube.com")
elem = api.find_elements_by_id("search")[1]
elem.send_keys("Your Search")
elem.submit()
```

Here you only have to change search and it works. Just download [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/new/) and the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.29.0/geckodriver-v0.29.0-win64.zip) put the geckodriver in the same directory as the script and tadah it should work.

Comment: I am still getting this error even though I ```pip install selenium```
No module named 'selenium' (vs code py3.9.1)

Comment: Have you tried ```py -m pip install selenium```

Comment: i am sorry if i am being needy but know what it means when ```'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.```